# Best way to expose cached objects to the views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, razor, view

I am using an Translator object (custom class) to expose website texts (the object stores texts from the database). The Translator object is stored in the cache, in the Application_Start() function.

My current use of the Translator object is:

- I have a MasterViewModel

  ```
  public class MasterViewModel
  {
      public Translator Translator = HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("Translator") as   Translator;
  }
  ```
- Every view has a viewmodel, that inherents from MasterViewModel

  ```
  public class RandomViewModel : MasterViewModel
  {
  }
  ```
- In my views i can use my Translator object

  ```
  @model ViewModels.RandomViewModel

  @Model.Translator.GetText(label)
  ```

I don't think this is a nice aproach. 
Is it a good idea to make a razor helper in App_Code, so that in my views i can use

```
    @Translate.GetText("RANDOM_TEXT")
```

This will be the Helper function (in Translate.cshtml)

```
    @helper GetText(string label)
    {
        Translator Translator = @Cache.Get("Translator") as Translator;
        @: Translator.GetTextByLabel(label);
    }
```

So my question is what is the best way of exposing a cached object to all my views.
Is one of the above approaches good? Or should i go with another solution?

(I hope my english is okay, i am dutch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways you can achieve that but I'll create a base class by deriving from `WebViewPage` and force all the razor views inherit from this class.

```
public abstract class MyWebViewPageBase<T>: WebViewPage<T>
{
   private Translator _translator;

   protected override void InitializePage()
   { 
     _translator = Context.Cache.Get("Translator") as Translator;
   }

   public string Translate(string label)
   {
     if(_translator != null)
       return _translator.GetText(label);

     return "";
   }
}
```

Now I can inherit the `MyWebViewPage` in razor views through couple of ways:

The first approach is from every view you have to use the `@inherits` directive.

Ex.

```
// Index.cshtml
@inherits MyWebViewPageBase
@model ...

....
```

The other approach is a global way of setting the base page for all the views and for that you have to modify the web.config that exists in the `Views` folder.

You have to set the `pageBaseType` of `pages` element as below,

```
<pages pageBaseType="MyWebViewPageBase">
```

Now from any view you can simply call the translate method as below,

```
@Translate("RANDOM_TEXT")
```

Hope this helps!