# Can I expose other objects to MVC views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In an MVC view, you can have code like this:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
{
    <li>Only the admin can see this menu item</li>
}
```

Can I expose other objects or custom classes to the view? How would I do so?

Comment: In a nutshell you're asking about the **M** in `MVC` so [here's a good place to start learning more about MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started)

Comment: No, actually, I'm asking about something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945840/best-way-to-expose-cached-objects-to-the-views but with a Partial View.

Answer (score 2):

One way is exposing what you have in the session, a singleton or something specific to every user:

```html
@{
    MyCustomClass myClass = (MyCustomClass)Session["MyCustomClass"];
    
    // call your methods here
    myClass.Init();
    myClass.VoidLastTransaction();
    var ID = myClass.CurrentID;
}
```

The other example, use a 'using', then assign a variable to an instance or just call out the static.

```html
@{
    using Namespace.Myspace.BL;

    var report = StaticClassFromBL.Class;
    report.Init();
}

<div>
    @report.Draw();
</div>
```

This is enough most of the time.

I do realize your question might have to do more with directly exposing an object without extra code, which is probably possible within the configs somewhere for the razor engine. I have not used that before.

**EDIT:**
For static objects you can add a using directly to the web.config file in the views folder and each area. This way your classes will be available by just calling @Class.Method() or within @{} brackets.

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>        
    <pages pageBaseType="Projectspace.Space.UILogic.ProjectView">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="StaticSpace.Models"/>
```

Hoping this helps.